# WordPress, шаблоны

Tags: wordpress, bootstrap, запрос, шаблоны

```
<?php 
    query_posts('page_id=124'); 
    if ( have_posts() ) :
    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
?>                       
<div class="entry" style="font-size:14px;">

    <?php the_content('Read the rest of this entry &raquo;'); ?> 

</div> 
<?php endwhile; endif; wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Где должно быть содержимое the_content? Куда отрисовывается этот шаблон?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Контент всегда в базе. Править его надо в админке по адресу `/wp-admin/post.php?post=124&action=edit`

Отрисовывается на экран - куда же ещё?

`query_posts()` категорически не рекомендуется использовать. Только `get_posts()` или `WP_Query`.

Comment: Спасибо, вы очень помогли. Если можно, еще вопрос: в этом файле ссылка на картинки [Best_Wordpress_Gallery id="3" gal_title="Студенческая жизнь"]. По какому адресу они будут находится?

Comment: Если ответ полезен, его стоит отметить как принятый галочкой внизу. Это поможет ориентироваться пользователям, которые ищут ответ на подобный вопрос.

Comment: Здесь не принято задавать несколько вопросов в рамках одного. Создайте новый вопрос.